# How could I write a health check for Jgroups under Inifinispan?

Tags: java, hibernate-search, infinispan, jgroups

So We have a problem where a penetration checker being run for something like 12 hours is causing Jgroups to disconnect and then it doesn't recover.

Obviously we need to [fix Jgroups so that it does recover](https://stackoverflow.com/q/42656580/206466), but if Jgroups is down, I also don't want the load balancer to treat it like the server is up. I've figured out how to communicate that to the load balancer, but I'm having problems figuring out how I can actually check the health of the channel communication, especially since it's Infininispan that's responsible for creating them (which itself is being created by hibernate/search).

I think if I could get my hands on the [Channel](http://jgroups.org/javadoc/org/jgroups/Channel.html)'s I could use those, though there might be a better approach, and I can't see a way to get the channels. Well, I did find [this](http://planet.jboss.org/post/how_to_hijack_a_jgroups_channel_inside_infinispan_jboss_and_get_away_with_it) which shows how to get the channels from the `DefaultCacheManager` but that just makes the question how do I get that cache manager. We're using Spring and it doesn't appear to be defined in jndi, so that's out, the parameter that initializes this stuff is just an xml config passed to hibernate. note: there's no application server just Tomcat and Spring 4.

```
jgroups 3.6.13
infinispan 8.1.0, 
hibernate search 5.3
```

How can I check to see if my channels in Jgroups are connected?

Answer (score 1):

The latest Infinispan version contains so called HealthCheckAPI, which does exactly what you need: http://blog.infinispan.org/2017/03/checking-infinispan-cluster-health-and.html

Comment: well that'll be cool for us I'm guessing 2 years from now... when the stars and moons and versions of everything align... but then the question will still be...

how do I get the `EmbeddedCacheManager`?

Comment: It's the interface that DefaultCacheManager implements :)

Comment: I know that... and the point I've been making is I have no idea how to get my hands on the instance of that because it's being constructed by hibernate search/infinispan xml.

Comment: Sorry I think I missed a sub-question... If you use Spring Caching support, you can obtain `EmbeddedCacheManager` by injecting it: https://github.com/infinispan/infinispan/blob/master/spring/spring4/spring4-embedded/src/main/java/org/infinispan/spring/support/embedded/InfinispanEmbeddedCacheManagerFactoryBean.java#L48

Answer (score 0):

By *disconnecting* I assume you mean the cluster falls apart and splits into multiple subclusters?

What do you mean when you say JGroups is *down*? A channel is never down until you disconnect or close it; in other words, a channel will always happily send messages even though the cluster may be split into multiple subclusters.

You can always reduce the likelihood of cluster splits (network partitions) by adjusting the configuration, e.g. by increasing the timeouts in the failure detection protocol (FD or FD_ALL).

Re: how to get a channel. If you run Infinispan, you must have a cache defined don't you? Because if you don't have a cache, no channel will be created (they're created only on demand). If you have a cache, the link you referenced shows you how to get the JChannel from the cache.

```
How can I check to see if my channels in JGroups are connected?
```

No sure what you mean here. If you have a cluster `{A,B,C,D,E.F}` and it splits into `{A,B,C}` and `{D,E,F}`, then all members in the first subcluster have the same view and all members in the second subcluster have a different but also the same view among themselves.

Comment: yeah but, that link assumes I have access to the CacheManager... which is being created by something else... I'm assuming, maybe incorrectly that I have to have the instance of CacheManager, that's been created, and I can't figure out how to do that.

but yes the cluster falls apart, sometimes we get split brain, sometimes other errors, but the node never rejoins the cluster, and I'm trying to detect that

Comment: my question may not be right, just trying to discern if the cluster is healthy, and if it's not, report the appropriate status to the load balancer.

Comment: No, you don't need a CacheManager, a simple cache will do (casting omitted): cache.getAdvancedCache().getRpcManager().getTransport() will get you the transport. Next, downcast to JGroupsTransport and then call getChannel()

Comment: If your problem is that you can't retrieve the CacheManager from Hibernate Search, maybe you should add appropriate tags.

Comment: @Flavius no idea if I need `CacheManager` or `Cache` or whatever, and where I'm supposed to retrieve that from if I'm building it myself on top of all this xml configured stuff. We have one exposed manually created `JChannel` that I've spent the last day turning into a spring bean, but I'm not even sure reading this now if checking connected, is the right answer.

Answer (score 0):

`jChannels` is a list of Spring `JChannel` Beans, `@Autowired`, if `master` we don't need to report down, because it can operate by itself, HealthState is just an enum that we return as an HTTP response body. This isn't a complete answer as we haven't dealt with infinispan.

```
    return jChannels.stream()
        .peek( jChannel -> logDebug( () -> jChannel.toString( false ) ) )
        .map( jChannel -> ( jChannel.getView() != null && (!isSlave || jChannel.getView().size() > 1 ) ) )
        .filter( Predicate.isEqual( false ) )
        .findAny()
        .map( b -> HealthState.CLUSTER_DISCONNECTED );
```

obviously the important thing here is to check the `jChannel.getView()`