# How can I make Jgroups reconnect even after a long period of time?

Tags: java, jgroups

So We have a problem where a penetration checker being run for something like 12 hours is causing Jgroups to disconnect, the slave doesn't rejoin  the cluster, split brain, some other issues that represent the lack of replication, and it doesn't recover.

```
<config xmlns="urn:org:jgroups"
        xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
        xsi:schemaLocation="urn:org:jgroups http://www.jgroups.org/schema/JGroups-3.6.xsd">
   <TCP bind_addr="NON_LOOPBACK"
        bind_port="${infinispan.jgroups.bindPort}"
        enable_diagnostics="false"
        thread_naming_pattern="pl"
        send_buf_size="640k"
        sock_conn_timeout="300"

        thread_pool.min_threads="${jgroups.thread_pool.min_threads:2}"
        thread_pool.max_threads="${jgroups.thread_pool.max_threads:30}"
        thread_pool.keep_alive_time="60000"
        thread_pool.queue_enabled="false"

        internal_thread_pool.min_threads="${jgroups.internal_thread_pool.min_threads:5}"
        internal_thread_pool.max_threads="${jgroups.internal_thread_pool.max_threads:20}"
        internal_thread_pool.keep_alive_time="60000"
        internal_thread_pool.queue_enabled="true"
        internal_thread_pool.queue_max_size="500"

        oob_thread_pool.min_threads="${jgroups.oob_thread_pool.min_threads:20}"
        oob_thread_pool.max_threads="${jgroups.oob_thread_pool.max_threads:200}"
        oob_thread_pool.keep_alive_time="60000"
        oob_thread_pool.queue_enabled="false"
   />
   <TCPPING async_discovery="true"
            initial_hosts="${infinispan.jgroups.tcpping.initialhosts}"
            port_range="1"/>
   />
   <MERGE3 min_interval="10000" 
           max_interval="30000" 
   />
   <FD_SOCK />
   <FD />
   <VERIFY_SUSPECT />
   <pbcast.NAKACK2 use_mcast_xmit="false"
                   xmit_interval="1000"
                   xmit_table_num_rows="50"
                   xmit_table_msgs_per_row="1024"
                   xmit_table_max_compaction_time="30000"
                   max_msg_batch_size="100"
                   resend_last_seqno="true"
   />
   <UNICAST3 xmit_interval="500"
             xmit_table_num_rows="50"
             xmit_table_msgs_per_row="1024"
             xmit_table_max_compaction_time="30000"
             max_msg_batch_size="100"
             conn_expiry_timeout="0"
   />
   <pbcast.STABLE stability_delay="500"
                  desired_avg_gossip="5000"
                  max_bytes="1M"
   />
   <pbcast.GMS print_local_addr="true"  join_timeout="15000"/>
   <pbcast.FLUSH />
   <FRAG2 />
</config>
```

versions

```
jgroups 3.6.13
infinispan 8.1.0, 
hibernate search 5.3
```

I'm wondering if we can change our jgroups configuration so that the cluster node will eventually be able to rejoin. Even after 12 hours of "attack" so that we don't have to restart the servers.

Answer (score 0):

Define *disconnect* for me first, please!

Regarding your stack, I have a few suggestions / questions:

- I suggest in general to use `tcp.xml` from the version you use and then modify it according to your needs
- TCPPING: does initial_hosts contain all cluster members?
- Replace FD with FD_ALL
- STABLE: desired_avg_gossip of 5s is a bit small; this generates more traffic than needed
- GMS.join_timeout of 15s is quite high; this is the startup time of the first member, and it also influences discovery time
- What do you need FLUSH for?

Comment: Disconnected, server has gone through failure detection, and ultimately removed the node from the group.

`tcp.xml` I know this was originally copied and modified from whatever infinispan had in 8.1.0.

TCPPING yes; FD_ALL, actually post posting this I changed it to FD_ALL2, but that hasn't gone through production yet. `GMS.join_timeout`, our server takes a long time to start up (60s minimum) maybe that's why. FLUSH, we probably don't copying a warning we got...

Comment: ```[WARN ] [2017.03.05 10:29:05] impl.DispatchMessageSender - HSEARCH200010: FLUSH is not present in your JGroups stack! FLUSH is needed to ensure messages are not dropped while new nodes join the cluster. Will proceed, but inconsistencies may arise!```

Comment: Take the FLUSH warning up with the HSEARCH guys. I remember that a very ancient version of Infinispan required it, but this should not be the case anymore.

Comment: yeah, maybe, I think we're on infinispan 8.1.0, hibernate search 5.3, and this warning happened this week...  I don't think that's ancient... oddly I only just added flush to deal with it, maybe I should leave it off. did update regarding what I mean by disconnected, hopefully it makes sense

Comment: I notice that `tcp.xml` uses `FD` not `FD_ALL` ... but `tcp-nio.xml` uses `FD_ALL`, should I be using `tcp-nio` as a base instead?

Comment: No, you can continue using `TCP`. Or switch to `TCP_NIO2`, but that's an orthogonal issue.